# Run Time Error '440'; Array index out of bounds, when referencing attachment by index

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook rule to run a script to save attachments.

I insert an `Err.Clear` right after `Set olAttach = olItem.Attachments.item(1)` to clear an error in the code but this eventually causes the rule to fail.

When I don't have the `Err.Clear` command the code stops and gives

> Run Time Error '440'; Array index out of bounds.

```
Public Sub April26(item As Outlook.MailItem)

'
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim myDate As Date
Dim olItems As Object
Dim olItem As Object
Dim olAttach As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

If olApp Is Nothing Then
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Flg = True
End If

Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

For Each olItem In olItems
    If olItem.ReceivedTime > Date Then
        If InStr(olItem.Body, "Michael Jordan") > 0 Then

            Set olAttach = olItem.Attachments.item(1) '<---
            'Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0               '<---

            If Not olAttach Is Nothing Then
                On Error GoTo Finished
                olAttach.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\Desktop\Outlook Downloads" & "\" & olAttach.FileName
                Set olAttach = Nothing
                Set olItem = Nothing
            End If

        End If
    End If
Next

Set olApp = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olItems = Nothing

Finished:
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set olAttach = olItem.Attachments.item(1)` will fail if there are no attachments, so you first need to check whether there are any attachments. You can't check for `If Not olAttach Is Nothing` as you already triggered a run-time error. Your code could be simplified a lot if you use the `item` argument passed to your sub - that is the mail which triggered the event: no need to loop over your inbox every time...

Comment: Hi Tim, the four emails I receive daily and have "Michael Jordan" in the body have attachments. Do you know a way I can count the four items and then stop the code once I have received the four items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to answer my question. The conditions of my code were to save the attachments from emails with "Michael Jordan" in the body. These emails were only sent out on the early morning (between 12 AM and 6 AM). I know that I there are only FOUR emails sent and each email has ONE attachment so I put a break in my loop once I have a total count for four attachments.

Below is my modified code

```
Public Sub April26(item As Outlook.MailItem)

'
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim myDate As Date
Dim olItems As Object
Dim olItem As Object
Dim olAttach As Object
Dim Date1 As String
Dim Date2 As String
Dim iAttachments As Integer

Date1 = Date & " " & TimeValue("6:00:00")
Date2 = Date & " " & TimeValue("00:00:00")


On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

If olApp Is Nothing Then
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Flg = True
End If

Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")



Set olItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items



For Each olItem In olItems
    If olItem.ReceivedTime < Date1 Then
    If olItem.ReceivedTime > Date2 Then
    If InStr(olItem.Body, "Michael Jordan") > 0 Then
    'MsgBox (olItem & " " & olItem.ReceivedTime)
    iAttachments = olItem.Attachments.Count + iAttachments

    Set olAttach = olItem.Attachments.item(1)

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    olAttach.SaveAsFile "C:\Desktop\Outlook Downloads" & "\" & olAttach.FileName

    Set olAttach = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing


    If iAttachments = 4 Then Exit For
    End If
    End If
    End If
Next


    Set olAttach = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olItems = Nothing



Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
        & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information to Darth Vader." _
        & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: April26" _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
        , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Exit Sub



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to there being no attachments.

With `On Error Resume Next` anticipated errors are bypassed. Since they are anticipated you will know how to handle them, or ignore if reasonable to do so.

```
Option Explicit

' Extra lines for running code from applications other than Outlook removed

Public Sub April26(olItem As MailItem)

    Dim myDate As Date
    Dim olAttach As Attachment

    If olItem.ReceivedTime > Date Then

        If InStr(olItem.Body, "Michael Jordan") > 0 Then

            ' Rare beneficial use of "On Error Resume Next"
            On Error Resume Next
            ' Bypass error if there is no attachment
            Set olAttach = olItem.Attachments.item(1)
            'If there is an error olAttach remains whatever it was before
            ' In this case it is the initial value of Nothing
            ' Remove error bypass as soon as the purpose is served
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not olAttach Is Nothing Then
                olAttach.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\Desktop\Outlook Downloads" & "\" & olAttach.fileName
                ' If this type of error handling is in a loop,
                '  reinitialize
                ' Set olAttach = Nothing
            End If

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```